# What 's the value of a matern covariance function at zero?

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm using Mathematica to simulate a Gaussian Process, and the modified bessel function of the second kind at zero is undefined (I get an error warning). Assuming the mathematica function is correct, what is the point of using a matern covariance, since most of the times we'll have to compute the covariance function for when $d(x,y)=||x-y||=0$

Edit: after the comment by whuber, I have the following question: For any allowed parameter value, when we take the limit to d->0, will we always obtain 1?
I'm working with a large data set, and doing a limit everytime I want to calculate the covariance at d=0 is going to take too much time...

Comment: The Matern function is not just $K_\nu$: it is multiplied by normalizing constants as well as the $\nu$ power of the distance.  *Mathematica* knows how to do this calculation: ask it to take the limit from above as the distance approaches zero.  Alternatively, you can read the value directly off the [MacLaurin Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function#Taylor_series_at_zero_and_spectral_moments).

Comment: @whuber Got it thanks. However, it only calculates the limit for fixed parameter values. Can I assume that it will always be 1 when the distance is zero?

Comment: The series representation I referenced indicates that is the case, provided $\nu\ne 1.$  However, I had no problem getting *Mathematica* to compute the limit for all parameters using its `Limit` function.